# JSON-LD: "Missing ',' or ']' in array declaration." on closing </script> tag

Tags: json-ld

I am marking up a local business page using Schema.org. I am trying to apply the `openingHoursSpecification` value using JSON-LD syntax, but I am receiving a syntax error when I validate through SDTT.

The error is on line 67 of my code, which only has the closing `</script>` tag.

I have tried moving the `],` on line 63 to line 66 to make sure the `opens` and `closes` value/objects are a part of the `openingHoursSpecification` array, but I only receive more errors. I am puzzled as to what the closing `</script>` tag has to do with my code.

#### Sample code:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "image": "http://www.website.com/example.png",
  "@id": "http://www.website.com",
  "name": "ExampleBusiness",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "addressLocality": "Houston",
    "addressRegion": "Texas",
    "postalCode": "xxxxx",
    "addressCountry": "United States"
  },
  "review": {
    "@type": "Review",
    "reviewRating": {
      "@type": "Rating",
      "ratingValue": "4",
      "bestRating": "5"
    },
    "author": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "xxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": xx.xx,
    "longitude": -xx.xx
  },
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "telephone": "+0000000000",
  "openingHoursSpecification": [
    {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday"
      ],
      "opens": "08:00",
      "closes": "17:00"
    }]
```

#### Error shown in SDTT:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the JSON-LD with a `{`, but it doesn’t end with a `}`. So, you need to add a `}` to the end:

```json
  }]
}
```

Another error: You need to quote all string values. So, this

```json
"latitude": xx.xx,
"longitude": -xx.xx
```

should be this

```json
"latitude": "xx.xx",
"longitude": "-xx.xx"
```

Comment: This worked out very well. Also the longitude and lattitude are numeric values in the original code, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's just a copy-paste error when posting this question, it looks like you are just missing a closing brace '}'. You are seeing the error on line 67 because it reaches the script tag while trying to parse the JSON because there is no closing brace to terminate the parser.

Should be able to just add '}'.

One site I often use to test JSON that seems malformed is https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I definitely didn't include the clossing '}' brace in the original code, but it's all working out now. Thank you for taking the time to post resourceful solutions :)